# rake preview generating site without styles

Tags: octopress

I've set up a vanilla Octopress blog & I am hosting on github pages, but am encountering some issues when using `rake preview`.

To help troubleshoot, here's a short list of changes I've made since setting up Octopress (that I can recall):

1. in _config.yml, changed the url to my domain
2. in _config.yml, changed root to "/"
3. in _config.yml, specified my github repo under 3rd party settings
4. added CNAME pointing to my domain in /public/github
5. added CNAMe pointing to my domain in /source/
6. made a post using `rake new_post`

Here's a description of the issues:

1. `http://localhost:4000` yields a 404, however, I **am** able to see my site at `http://localhost:4000/github/index.html`
2. When previewing /github/index.html, most of the stylesheets/JS are returning a 404.

Here's what happens when I run `rake generate`, followed by `rake preview`:

```
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
Configuration from /Users/[redacted]/Documents/code/octopress/_config.yml
[2013-09-09 10:21:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-09-09 10:21:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
[2013-09-09 10:21:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=39870 port=4000
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public/github
[2013-09-09 10:21:45] regeneration: 95 files changed
>>> Change detected at 10:21:45 to: screen.scss
identical public/github/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley

>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Python 2.x. You should be able to check your Python version at the command prompt with `python --version`

If you don't have it then if you are on Windows, download and install Python 2.7.6 from `http://www.python.org/download/`
 then add `C:\Python27` (or the folder where you installed Python) to your path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `destination` setting in `_config.yml`. Default should be something like this:

```
root: /
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
source: source
destination: public
```